# Is there a way to get a string path reference to an embedded resource file?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method that takes a string parameter that is a file path to a text file.  I want to be able to pass in a text file that I have embedded as a resource in my assembly.

Is there any way to get a string reference to an embedded text file so that it would function as a file path for opening a StreamReader?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource_name_of_the_file)` to access the file's stream, write it to TEMP directory and use this path.

For example, if you have a file in your project at the path "**Resources\Files\File.txt**" and the project's assembly default namespace is "**RootNamespace**", you can access the file's stream from within this assembly's code with

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("RootNamespace.Resources.Files.File.txt")
```

Comment: After many hours of searching, I can confirm that this is the only way (afaik).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400140/how-do-i-automatically-delete-tempfiles-in-c

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any way to get a string reference to an embedded text file so that it would function as a file path for opening a StreamReader?

No, an embeded resource is not a separate file but embedded into the executable file. However, you can get a stream that you can read from using a `StreamReader`.

```
var name = "...";
using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(name)) 
  using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
    // Read the embedded file ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One method that worked for my  use case was from the following answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34664553/11860907

For Binary files: `File.WriteAllBytes(outputpath, Properties.Resources.file);`

For Text files: `File.WriteAllText(outputpath, Properties.Resources.file);`

I just ran this line of code for every embedded resource file I needed when my program first opened and it placed the resource files somewhere that I could then reference as a string path.