# Save image from resource file to computer - c#

Tags: c#, image, file, resources, save

Okei, I have a C# project with a resource file.
The resource file contains a image (.png).
I want the png file to be saved/extracted to a specified folder on my computer.
How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything

Comment: Apart from Adrian's engagement, the question is a very good one, I even searched for the same keywords combination, which is how I got here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    static void ExtractFileResource(string resource_name, string file_name)
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(file_name))
                File.Delete(file_name);

            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(file_name)))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(file_name));

            using (Stream sfile = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource_name))
            {
                byte[] buf = new byte[sfile.Length];
                sfile.Read(buf, 0, Convert.ToInt32(sfile.Length));

                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(file_name))
                {
                    fs.Write(buf, 0, Convert.ToInt32(sfile.Length));
                    fs.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Can't extract resource '{0}' to file '{1}': {2}", resource_name, file_name, ex.Message), ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I get "resource_name"?

Comment: You can loop through `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()` enumeration, it contains file names for all resources in the assembly. Or replace `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` with reference to assembly with resources if it's different.

Comment: Could you show an example?

Comment: `foreach (string resource_name in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()) if(ItsMyResource(resource_name)) ExtractFileResource(resource_name, file_path);` Something like this

Comment: Please, don't forget to make answer accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

See this Page It could help : [MSDN Save Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

[Extracting-Embedded-Images-From-An-Assembly](http://codeproject.com/Articles/13573/Extracting-Embedded-Images-From-An-Assembly)
or

[how-can-i-extract-a-file-from-an-embedded-resource-and-save-it-to-disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031778/how-can-i-extract-a-file-from-an-embedded-resource-and-save-it-to-disk)

This?