# Extracting a .zip to location in runtime C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, zip, extract

I have been looking for a solution but cannot find a way how to do this.

I have a .zip which is an embedded resource and I need to extract it to a location but i'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here: [How can I extract a file from an embedded resource and save it to disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031778/how-can-i-extract-a-file-from-an-embedded-resource-and-save-it-to-disk)
Followed by this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx