# Add folder to resources of C# application and merge to single exe

Tags: c#

All i need is copy folder from my c# exe to user directory .i cannot have folder separate from exe.i can have only one exe.Is there anyway to marge a folder inside my c# exe file.so then i can paste it to user directory when execute it.but i cannot use a installer setup .i can have only single exe and it should paste a folder which is inside of exe to the user directory.

Comment: Maybe embed the files as a resource in the EXE, and read them as a stream, or uncompress them to the target directory when the program loads?

Comment: @MikeChristensen yes i want to uncompress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it simple.

1. Add files to the project as embedded resources
2. Create a folder from your application
3. Extract resource files and save them to that folder

You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031778/how-can-i-extract-a-file-from-an-embedded-resource-and-save-it-to-disk) answer on stackoverflow to help in extracting embedded files and save them.