# Access VBS file located in Resources.resx and execute it?

Tags: c#, vbscript, process, resources

I have a .vbs file working perfectly, but only when I put it into the Debug folder. I want to get it from the Resources folder, so when the person executes the .exe file it will be there already. Any tips on how I can do this?

This is the piece of code I am using so far:

```
         Process scriptProc = new Process();
        //scriptProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"file.vbs";
        scriptProc.StartInfo.Arguments = path;
        MessageBox.Show(scriptProc.StartInfo.FileName = @config + ".vbs");
        scriptProc.Start();
        scriptProc.WaitForExit();
        scriptProc.Close();
```

Comment: extract resource to temp path & then execute it !.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! Do you have any examples on how to do that? This is a "secret" file too as well, so the user could not see them at any moment, wouldn't this method be unsafe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this answer : [How can I extract a file from an embedded resource and save it to disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031778/how-can-i-extract-a-file-from-an-embedded-resource-and-save-it-to-disk)

Now regarding the comment about this file must be a secret, i would say :

> if a file can be executed on user PC it certain can be accessed, all u
>   can do make the accessing part hard, that way not everyone would be
>   able to access it.

The script file u have cannot be executed by extracting it from memory (unless you write your own `script runner`). For now all you can do is extract file to temp path, execute it and delete it.

Comment: Thank you for replying, this actually kinda helped me! I mean kinda mainly because I couldn't understand this piece of code, but instead I found a video-tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_61pLVH2qPk) which helped me a lot. It's the exact same logic, but he doesn't use a string array. It works just fine, tho. Maybe later I will focus on using a string array to make the code look better. Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: Edit: To make the file "secret", I made sure to make it hidden and delete right after using it. So the file is available for like 5 seconds only & it's hidden. Thanks again!

Comment: @DiegoFortes - glad i could be of help !

Answer (score 0):

To access VBS files (or any other kind of files) located in Resources.resx (or any other folder) and execute it simply follow this step-by-step tutorial w/ source-code included, that's how I made it!

If you get any erros about values being null, try doing this:

1. Go to the folder where the files are located within Visual Studio;
2. Right click on the file and select "Properties";
3. On "Build Action" select "Embedded Resource".

Good luck!!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_61pLVH2qPk