# Merging a c executable, managed COM dll, and .Net gui

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, com

**packetlistener.exe**: I have a c application that actively listens and receives packets.

**comwrapper.dll**: A C++ COM dll that wraps the unmanaged c executable

**guiapp.exe**: A .NET gui that references the comwrapper.dll and uses it to display information and handle events.

The way I am currently launch the application:

1. Start packetlistener.exe with command line argument.
2. Start guiapp.exe

I have spent the last couple of hours trying to figure out how to package this nicely into one process.

What I have tried to do is compile packetlistener.exe as a dll and then include it in the guiapp project. However, I am completely lost regarding starting packetlistener as part of guiapp.

I am new to windows development and feel like I am doing something wrong.
Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: If you have the source code of the C-program either create a DLL out of it. Write a COM interface to it, or embed it into a C++/CLI code and use it directly as a .NET assembly. But what is your question? JUst having one executable? Directly use the code without having a separate process?

Comment: I would like to just have one executable without two separate processes.

The C program runs as an executable and the COM interface is able to query it for data and send commands but only if the executable is already running. 

Can I convert the C application into a DLL and then start it from within my C# program?


The c program is actually open sourced by apple. https://opensource.apple.com/source/mDNSResponder/mDNSResponder-765.50.9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up figuring out what I wanted to do.

I compiled my C application into a DLL and exposed a function that would get it started.

I then used PInvoke to call that function in a separate thread so that it can start gathering and sending packets.

The COM DLL magically seems to referrence the C program thats running in its own thread.

Now since I am unable to PInvoke a DLL thats embedded I had to unpack it in a temp file you can learn about that in here.

[How can I extract a file from an embedded resource and save it to disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031778/how-can-i-extract-a-file-from-an-embedded-resource-and-save-it-to-disk).

In the end I was left with one executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a process from a .net application using [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Process.Start("packetlistener.exe", "-arg1 -arg2");
```

Comment: Does this requires "packetlistener.exe" to be in a separate file?
Is it possible to build packetlistener.exe as an dll and then start it with .net?

Comment: Yes. If you use process.start, it needs to be a separate exe on disk.

Comment: I've just done this and it opens a seperate cmd prompt. I was wondering how I can merge these into one application.

Comment: There are lots of options to control how Process.Start works. Read the [ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) docs. You can launch the process and not show a window and redirect the output to your application.  If you want to try and consume the library via COM, you can try that, but COM does add complexity.

Comment: I have a COM that interacts with "packetlistener.exe" but the COM itself does not start it. Which is the main problem. In fact packetlistener.exe used to be a service that I am now running as a console application